# One overall subscript with double integral?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I want to assign only one overall subscript that cover the both integral symbols in double integration, I tried:

```
\begin{equation}
T_y=\iint_A \tau_{xy}\,dA=0
\end{equation}
```

but it only goes with second integral?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\iiint\limits_V \mu(t,u,v,w) \,dt\,du\,dv\,dw\]
\end{document}
`

Comment: But this is not working if I put inside equation environment, what to do?

Comment: Of course it does.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\iiint\limits_V \mu(t,u,v,w) \,dt\,du\,dv\,dw\]
\begin{equation}
 T_y=\iint\limits_A \tau_{xy}\,dA=0
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
`

Comment: Fine got it, I need to remove `\[ ` and `\] ` when us it in equation.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Triple integral

Comment: @Johannes_B, please convert your comment to answer :-)

Comment: @Zarko That was asked before, i am sure. I couldn't find a suitable dupe though.

Comment: @Johannes_B, well, when it cannot be found: Please convert your comment to answer :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\limits` to accomplish the job. The package `mathtools` provides good enhancements to the basic features of LaTeX typesetting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\iiint\limits_V \mu(t,u,v,w) \,dt\,du\,dv\,dw \\
T_y=\iint\limits_A \tau_{xy}\,dA=0
\end{gather} 
\end{document}
```

[image]